# Showing that a closed unit ball is not compact

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $B[0, 1]$ be the space of all bounded functions on $[0, 1]$. Show that the closed unit
ball $D = \{f \in B[0, 1] : \|f\| \leq 1 \}$ is not compact in $(B[0, 1], \|.\|_{\infty})$.

can we reason as follows. If a closed unit ball which is bounded  of a Normed Linear Space is compact then the space should be finite dimesional. But $X=B[0,1]$ is not finite dimensional.
Hence it is not compact?
Will this work?

Comment: it does work (now)

Comment: That's correct, but there's more direct ways to show it without that fact. You can try to violate sequential compactness, for example.

Answer (score 3):

If $(E_n)$ is any disjoint sequence of subsets of $[0,1]$ then $(I_{E_n})$ has no convergent subsequence. [This avoids using the theorem on finite dimensionality under compactness of the unit ball].

Comment: You mean the indicator functions?  And distinct subsets will do.

Comment: @OrestBucicovschi You are right.